# Invalid API Issue in Zoho Catalyst

Tags: catalystbyzoho

I have been working with Zoho Catalyst functions and web client for the past 3 months. All of a sudden it now throws Invalid API Issue as shown below.

```
{
 "status": "failure",
 "data": {
   "message": "Invalid API URL with method GET",
   "error_code": "INVALID_URL"
  }
}
```

This seems to work fine in my local environment, but in development the entire application is inaccessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue might arise if you have enabled API Gateway for your Catalyst project. If you have enabled API Gateway, the URLs of all your web client and functions will become inaccessible until you create APIs for them. You can either create APIs for your client or you can disable the API Gateway from your Catalyst console and then access the application URL directly to resolve the mentioned issue. You can find the help documentation for API Gateway [here](https://docs.catalyst.zoho.com/en/cloud-scale/help/api-gateway/introduction/).